# BigInteger java method to gmp c++

Tags: c++

I want to convert java code in c++

code is

```
BigInteger value = new BigInteger(125, RandomNumber); 
BigInteger clone = new   BigInteger(value.toByteArray());
```

How to write this code in cpp using gmp library?

Please anyone help me.
Thanks.

Comment: #include<gmp.h>                                                             mpz_t value;                                                              mpz_init2(randomnumber,125);

Comment: I recommend have a look at the documentation. If you did so already, you describe what problems you are facing with your code.

Comment: `gmp_randstate_t state; gmp_randinit_default(state);` to initialize the RNG, then `mpz_t value; mpz_urandomb(value, state, 125);` to generate the random number. Completely untested, I'm just reading the documentation.

Comment: I want a 125 bit random number from current time using gmp.              Can you please let me tell how it get?

Comment: Thanks i get 125 bit number from random number. i want random number from current time in milisecond

Comment: A number taken from the current time isn't a random number. So I'm not sure what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With C++ you can do that

```
#include <gmpxx.h>
#include <gmp.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  mpz_class value;
  mpz_class clone;
  gmp_randclass r(gmp_randinit_default);
  value = r.get_z_bits(125);
  clone = value;
  cout << value << endl;
  cout << clone << endl;                                                                                                                                                                     
  return 0;
}
```

and compile with
g++ file.cpp -lgmpxx -lgmp

to install libgmpxx.a
put --enable-cxx to the build option of ./configure

Comment: I am using VC++. I am using gmp.h and gmp.lib file. How i use gmpxx.h?

Comment: Please help me how i use gmpxx.h in VC++ project

Comment: You can try this: http://www.exploringbinary.com/how-to-install-and-run-gmp-on-windows-using-mpir/

Answer (score 0):

here is a carbon copy from wikipedia

Here is an example of C code showing the use of the GMP library to multiply and print large numbers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gmp.h>

int main(void)
{
 mpz_t x;
 mpz_t y;
 mpz_t result;

 mpz_init(x);
 mpz_init(y);
 mpz_init(result);

 mpz_set_str(x, "7612058254738945", 10);
 mpz_set_str(y, "9263591128439081", 10);

 mpz_mul(result, x, y);
 gmp_printf("\n    %Zd\n*\n    %Zd\n--------------------\n%Zd\n\n", x, y, result);

 /* free used memory */
 mpz_clear(x);
 mpz_clear(y);
 mpz_clear(result);
 return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This code calculates the value of 7612058254738945 × 9263591128439081.

Compiling and running this program gives this result. (The -lgmp flag is used if compiling on Unix-type systems.)

```
    7612058254738945
*
    9263591128439081
--------------------
70514995317761165008628990709545
```